# Kafka Streams API - joining two tables with many to many relationship

Tags: apache-kafka, kafka-consumer-api, apache-kafka-streams

I have two streams coming to Kafka:

- Stream A: pairs of [userID, country]
- Stream B: pairs of [docID, country]

I just need to know existance of a pair so value can be `true/null`. Multiple users and multiple documents can share multiple countries, so relationships are many to many in both cases. Single user can have multiple countries assigned to them and a single doc can have many countries assigned to it.

What I need in the end topic/KTable are triples (userID, country, docID) with `true/null` values (so I can add or remove them downstream from the storage).

What I am not managing to figure out, how to use Kafka's Stream API to achieve this. I have tried various joins, but they work only on exact keys (which makes sense for distributed systems), but feels like restricts me from achieving this.

Comment: could you explain the relation between user, doc and country

Comment: @GuangshengZuo it says that it is many to many. I added more clarity to the question

Comment: Kafka is pretty unimpressing at symmetrical joins. What you will end up is caching all entries for both users and docs in memory and then doing lookups each time new message arrives. You can parition it by country possibly to pretend you utilize kafka capabilities, but ask yourself is kafka is a right tool for this problem - this sounds a lot more fitting task for some kind of database (be it SQL or noSQL)

Comment: @eddyP23 What you means is if [useID, country] [docID, country] has same country, then can be combined into a triple ?

Comment: @GuangshengZuo, yes indeed.

Comment: I agree the @ArturBiesiadowski suggestion.

Comment: There is a JIRA ticket to add non-key joins to Kafka Streams: https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/KAFKA-3705 But it's not available atm. It's quite tricky to implements. There is an open PR already in case you want to give it a shot to implement a custom solution via your own processor.

Comment: Hi, what is the status of this at the moment ?